# Identifying Key Changes in Crudelis Herodes Deum by Zelenka

Tags: key, analysis, modulation

"Crudelis Herodes Deum" was written by Jan Dismas Zelenka in 1732.The piece as a whole is in G minor, but I need help with telling when the key modulates or changes. [Here](https://ks4.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/9/9b/IMSLP380362-PMLP614320-ZWV_112.pdf) is the original copy, and [here](https://www.noteflight.com/scores/view/5bc044314e09d5927891c284ab9858dff71c032a) is the one I have edited. (I changed the different clefs to just treble and bass clef.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the composer would have considered this to be "in G minor." More likely, he was writing in a transposed Church Mode. As such, trying to analyze it in detail in terms of common-practice key changes is likely to end up somewhere between "anachronistic" and "futile".

Considering the composition date, it was probably intended to be performed in an unequal temperament (for example mean-tone). Therefore, there are a limited number of major and minor chords that are "well tempered", and the harmonic progression meanders between those chords with little regard for the classical-era concept of "tonality". Note also that some "dissonant" 7th chords were actually more consonant in mean-tone tuning than they are in modern equal temperament.

The figured bass notation should give you another was to cross-check your transcription - if the figured bass harmonies don't fit, something is wrong somewhere!

Comment: It's going to be exacerbated by the fact that Zelenka was something of a modernist in his time (about the same time as Bach), but the hymn is probably elaborating a Dorian antiphon (at a guess, 1st transposition of the 1st tone). The temperament would have varied depending on the continuo instrument: a mean tone tuning of some sort if the organ (some are meaner than others); probably something akin to French _ordinaire_ if the harpsichord. The fact that it's early 18th century Catholic choral music is going to impose a certain conservatism (but the Italian sixth in the 3rd measure!...).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're looking for modulations, focus on **cadences**. Listen through the piece once (and ideally a few more times) and mark spots where you sense a cadence.

Then determine exactly what these cadence are---half cadence, deceptive cadence, authentic cadence?---and what key(s) they're in. Once you know the goals, then you can determine exactly how the modulations are achieved. (But note that, in the Baroque period, most cadences are achieved either by common-chord modulation [also called pivot-chord] or through use of a sequence.)

For instance, there's a clear cadence in m. 8; closer examination shows that it's an authentic cadence in B-flat major, the relative major of G minor. This isn't the only cadence, but it's a start.

And one final note: you've got a number of errors in your NoteFlight score; be aware of this as you're doing the analysis!

(Sorry if my answer lacks the specifics you were looking for. In this case, I feel more comfortable *leading you to the answer* instead of just giving it.)

Comment: Could you be more specific on the mistakes? This is for a class and I am having trouble fixing it so it is correct.

Comment: Be careful with the accidentals - "b quadratum" (as in the key signatures) is a flat, but " b rotundum" (as in bar 34) is a natural. When you changed the key signature from one to two flats, check you haven't changed any E naturals into E flats. Also, you have some of the parts playing back in the wrong octave - The C clefs in the original are all literally middle-C, unlike modern tenor-voice parts written in a different octave from how they sound.

Comment: @KatieMelissaAnderson m. 7 stuck out to be especially.

Comment: Note also that the rest in the descant in m.3 doesn't exist in the original - the first note is dotted. In manuscripts of the period, dots usually appear at the point where the next note would have started had the first note been undotted. This means that you may well run across notes that are dotted across the bar line rather than tied - the dot comes after the bar line.